# Inserting Time in H2 Database - Function "PARSEDATETIME" not found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, h2

I have this table

```
   -- table T_TIME_LAPSE H2 Database Engine
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_time_lapse (
      id          bigint  PRIMARY KEY,
      name        varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      description varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      sunday      boolean DEFAULT NULL,
      monday      boolean DEFAULT NULL,
      tuesday     boolean DEFAULT NULL,
      wednesday   boolean DEFAULT NULL,
      thursday    boolean DEFAULT NULL,
      friday      boolean DEFAULT NULL,
      saturday    boolean DEFAULT NULL,
      init_period date    NOT NULL ,
      end_period  date    NOT NULL ,
      init_time   time    DEFAULT NULL,
      end_time    time    DEFAULT NULL,
      company_id  bigint DEFAULT NULL,
 );
```

Where I try to insert values of TIME Type (* the date data type. The format is yyyy-MM-dd.Mapped to java.sql.Date, with the time set to 00:00:00 (or to the next possible time if midnight doesn't exist for the given date and timezone due to a daylight saving change).)

```
    -- table     t_time_lapse
insert into T_TIME_LAPSE (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, INIT_PERIOD, END_PERIOD, INIT_TIME, END_TIME, COMPANY_ID) 
    values (1777,'key', 'key', 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PARSEDATETIME('12:22','HH:mm'), PARSEDATETIME('16:22','HH:mm'), 1);
```

but I got this error

```
Function "PARSEDATETIME" not found; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your Syntax you miss the `''` in your query

```
PARSEDATETIME('16:22', 'HH:MM'), 1)
//---------------------^-----^
```

Check the syntax how it should be your date with H2 [parsedatetime](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#parsedatetime)

so your query should end like this :

```
..., PARSEDATETIME('12:22', 'HH:mm'), PARSEDATETIME('16:22', 'HH:mm'), 1));
```